# How much money would be saved if Parliament Hill flags were replaced only when frayed?

Tags: canada

1. What's the cost of replacing the 5 current [Parliament Hill flags](https://www.tpsgc-pwgsc.gc.ca/citeparlementaire-parliamentaryprecinct/decouvrez-discover/drapeaux-flags-eng.html)?
2. What'd be the cost of replacing these 5 flags only when truly necessary, e.g. when they get frazzled, or must be adjusted to and from half-mast? I don't know the durability (against weather) or longevity of the flags.

> Five flags fly on the Hill: one over the Peace Tower, one on each side of the Centre Block, one over the West Block and one over the East Block.
>
> [...]
>
> ### The flag master
>
> Every weekday, the designated flag master changes the Peace Tower flag, except on statutory holidays and during poor weather conditions. The flag is also changed for [half-masting](http://canada.pch.gc.ca/eng/1444133232495). The other Parliament Hill flags are changed weekly and on days that they are at half-mast.

Comment: Changed does not mean the previous flag is disposed of.  Like clothes, they could be washed and re-used multiple times.

Comment: @Caleth "they could be " are they though?

Comment: It's also not clear to me that this is a question about politics.

Answer (score 2):

According to the transcript of the video you linked to, only 1 flag is changed daily, while the other flags are changed weekly:

> There's five flags on Parliament Hill: one on the East Block, one on the West Block and two on the courtesy poles, and they get changed once a week. And there's the fifth one, the most important one, it's the one on the Peace Tower, and that flag is changed daily, every working day.

The changed flags are not thrown away, but are given to patriotic Canadians who request them:

> So once the flag is taken down changed we keep 'em, we fold 'em in a specific way and we hold ‘em for the Minister's Office for Public Works, and they're responsible to deliver the flags to the Canadians who have put their names on the list.

So, while I  can't put a dollar amount on this, I would argue that any expenditures related to this are considered service for patriotic citizens, not a maintenance expense. So while you might save ~$50,000/year (assuming 350 less flag changes and $150/flag), making this change would probably be seen as an action driven by anti-patriotism (ie. you want to stop the flag gifting) rather than efficiency.

Comment: Yes. I did fancy knowing how much money would be saved if the 'service for patriotic citizens' or 'flag gifting' were cancelled. I don't think this is 'anti-patriotism': the gov't can charge for these flags.